# Why does TeamViewer think that I am in a commercial environment?

Tags: window, teamviewer

I have been using TeamViewer for ten years or more. Suddenly, I am getting this:

[image]

I am at home and using only my laptop and a desktop that I use as a file server - at home, ***not*** in a commercial environment.

I uninstalled & reinstalled TeamViewer on both, to no avail. Any ideas? Did anyone already have this problem & solve it?

Comment: They want you to pay for it. You can argue til you're blue in the face… they may or may not reverse their decision, but there's nothing anyone here can do. *Signed, an ex-teamviewer user with the same issue.*

Comment: Not an answer, but it happened to me too - I had a commercial license that I could only use with customers, and then I needed *also* a version for personal use to connect to my own box at home (or sometimes with friends or relatives with PC problems). They both worked for a few months, then stopped; I contacted TeamViewer and they fixed it, but it happened again after some time.
In the end I now use AnyDesk for personal use.

Comment: I abandoned teamviewer a long time ago when this happened to me. And yes, I too use it only personally. I now use RDP and AnyDesk

Comment: How many hours do you use it for? Can you bypass connecting through their servers and connect directly to the machine instead?

Comment: How many hours? Historically, hundreds, maybe thousands. Now I get that warning instantly and it allows me only a few minutes of use before closing

Comment: @LPChip do you have URLs for what you use?

Comment: Looks like a licensing question to me. Contact TeamViewer support.

Comment: google anydesk. RDP is Microsofts buildin Remote Desktop. You have windows, it comes with it.

Comment: @DanielB I tried contacting them in the past, they said if the teamviewer software suspects commercial use, its probably going to be that. I could get rid of the message by buying a commercial license. They did not want to see it any other way.

Comment: Yes, they won’t be inclined to help non-paying customers. That’s clear. However, there’s really nothing anyone else could do to solve this question.